# How to configure docker to work with byebug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, docker-compose

I have a legacy Rails 5.1 app. We have recently started to use docker-compose. We use puma and nginx to start the app like:

```
bundle exec puma -d && nginx -g "daemon off;"
```

Using this mapping for pots:

```
version: '3'
services:
  ...
  web:
    ports:
      - 3001:80
```

The works just fine (but i can not see any logs from rails app).
I need to be able to use byebug gem to debug my Rails app.

I have tried this but without any luck:

```
web: ...
  stdin_open: true
  tty: true
```

```
  $ docker-compose up -d

  $ docker attach app_web_1
```